# constant spin loading but no image popping up - colorbox

Tags: colorbox

When clicking the links, I get the popup box as expected however the images won't load, it just spins and spins. all the paths are ok as far as I can see.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox/colorbox.css" />
<script src="colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>  
<p><a class="group1" href="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/colorbox/content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="Me and my grandfather on the Ohoopee.">Grouped Photo 1</a></p>
<p><a class="group1" href="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/colorbox/content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as a child">Grouped Photo 2</a></p>
<p><a class="group1" href="http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/colorbox/content/ohoopee1.jpg" title="On the Ohoopee as an adult">Grouped Photo 3</a></p>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
            $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
            $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
            $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", widt  h:"75%", height:"75%"});
            $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
            $(".ajax").colorbox();
            $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640,  innerHeight:390});
            $(".vimeo").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:500,  innerHeight:409});
            $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%",  height:"80%"});
            $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
            $(".callbacks").colorbox({
                onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to  open'); },
                onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started  to load the targeted content'); },
                onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has  displayed the loaded content'); },
                onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has  begun the close process'); },
                onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has  completely closed'); }
            });

            $('.non-retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none'})
            $('.retina').colorbox({rel:'group5', transition:'none',  retinaImage:true, retinaUrl:true});

            //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
            $("#click").click(function(){ 
                $('#click').css({"background-color":"#f00",  "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still  be here.");
                return false;
            });
});
```

and a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Kuaet/2/

Chrome console gives these errors which are general as far as I can see and not related to this (although I know, they need sorting!)

GET http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/resources/demos/style.css 404 (Not Found) newsliderdev.asp:20
GET http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/ahkerrigan-light-webfont.woff 404 (Not Found) newsliderdev.asp:1
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://www.paycoservices.co.uk/ahkerrigan-light-webfont.ttf".

Comment: Updated the question with chrome console errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using various versions of colorbox and jQuery I finally found a set that works well together and solves this issue as it was simply down to the versions of colorbox and jQuery I was using. jQuery 1.6.4 and the current version of colorbox work together perfectly.